# Getting the access to the System.Printing namespace in .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is there a way to get access to the [System.Printing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.printing.printqueue?view=netcore-3.1) namespace from a .net core console application. I see it is available for a .net core WPF application. There is nothing in the documentation that specifies it is only available for WPF.

I have looked for System.Printing NuGet package with no luck

I am using C# .NET Core 3.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Sort of. If you set up your project file to use WPF (`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">`, `<UseWpf>true</UseWpf>`) but leave the `<OutputType>` at `Exe`, you will have a console app with a `Main` that can do whatever it likes -- in particular, it doesn't need to actually offer any WPF GUI. I say "sort of" because this application will of course still be tied to Windows, this setup is probably not supported, and it may fail in unexpected ways if you need to pull in other, non-WPF code. Caveat lector.

Comment: It has a checkered history.  Originally completed at .NET 2.0, but they decided not to include it because it wasn't good enough.  But WPF took a dependency on it so they had no choice but ship it in 3.0.  So you really do need to create a WPF project to get it, you don't have to create any UI.  Do beware the trouble, it *really* isn't good enough to manage print queues.

Comment: Depending on what you need, and assuming a windows target.. you could also PInvoke your way to the finish line.  There are decent PInvoke wrappers for win32 printing on the web.  Please note.. if this were an easy route, it would have already been done and part of the core framework.

Answer (score 14):

Add the following framework reference to your .csproj file to be able to reference the `System.Printing` namespace:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Sources: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/871#issuecomment-501498045
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/cpp-cli

Sample:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```